# give div the width of background-image

Tags: html, css

So I am making a gallery-page and I am trying to find a way to scale the divs according to the given background-image.

This is what I have so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FzJDy
but this is a problematic solution as if the image is too big, it overflows its' parent div. I want to show the full image, so `overflow:hidden` is not an option.

I know that a way to solve this is by using `background-image` on a div rather than an img tag. and then do `background-size: contain` but this is also problematic since (I think) it only works when the parent div has a fixed width and height.

Is there a solution to this if both the div and background-image sizes are unknown?

TL;DR

How to scale a picture to its' parent div if the parent div takes same dimensions as containing image?

thanks.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Try rephrasing and providing clearer examples.

Comment: @Boaz, hmm. Could you please tell me what's confusing you and I'll try to rephrase/clarify that part?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from your .white-content CSS...

```
max-width: 75%;
max-height: 75%;
```

Then set your .galleryfullsize CSS to...

```
.galleryfullsize {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height: 75%;
}
```

Comment: The pictures can get extremely big without a max width and height. I want them to fit on screen.

Comment: Edited answer, just set the max-width and max-height on the image class instead of the div class.

Comment: Then you get a lot of white area around the image within the div.

Comment: Try setting it to max-width:100% and max-height:75%, looked okay in codeproject but it's hard to really tell with it only covering the bottom of the viewport.